# Convert null integer into zero(0) in where clause using linq

Tags: c#

i am getting data from user table using linq in this table i have two field AgencyID (int) and MemberID (int) in table these fields are null values when i am calling data by using below query it does not find any record although it exists, reason is that this part (Where(x.AgencyID== null && x.MemberID == null) have to be pass '0' instead of null how i convert it into zero 
i have tried

```
return View(db.vt_Users.Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true &&
                                   x.AgencyID == null &&
                                   x.MemberID == null)
                       .ToList());
```

Comment: If the values are null, then the types of `MemberId` and `AgencyId` should be `int?` rather than `int`. Basically, your question is confusing at the moment...

Comment: Does AgencyID and MemberID field in DB is Nullable means Allow Null is true or false ? Also What is DB record contains 0 or null.

Comment: yes its Nullable. its data type is int